# Fragmant not showing in frame layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout, android-recyclerview, android-framelayout

My framelayout is not replacing fragments. I think my layout have some issue. If I add recyclerview inside linearlayout I am able to see frangment change. But recyclerview postion is change. Please help

Home page Laout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"

android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>



    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frameone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" />


    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Fragment commit code:

```
   private void selectItem(int position) {

    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new TopNewsFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FixturesFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new TableFragment();
            break;


        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {

       FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) 
        findViewById(R.id.content_frameone);
        frameLayout.removeAllViews();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frameone, fragment);
        ft.commit();



        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    } else {
        Log.e("RssfeedActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

Fragment page code

```
  import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

 public class TopNewsFragment extends Fragment {

public TopNewsFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_news, container, 
  false);

    return rootView;
}

}
```

Igf i add recyclerview inside Linear layout i am getting like this.
[image]

Comment: Try setting the `FrameLayout`'s height to `wrap_content`.

Comment: Not working..Tried that

Comment: What your fragment's layout look like? Can you provide the XML code?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Display content here"/>

</LinearLayout>

Comment: Its just empty.Only one text view is der.Main probilem if i click my navigation drawer fragment not replaing in frame layout

Comment: 1. Can you also provide the fragment's Java code? But this time, please, edit your question, and add the formatted code there.
2. Did you try to wrap the first `LinearLayout` within a `ScrollView` just to see if anything is below the `RecyclerView`?

Comment: Hi updated fragment java code

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frameone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried this.THen Recyclerview fiting perfect.But my fragment is not replacing inside frame layout

Comment: can you share here your fragment xml ?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Display content here"/>

</LinearLayout>

Comment: At present only one text view in my fragment xml

Comment: add background color in your fragment xml parent

Comment: Can we move to chat?